# Pagination through Struts2 using DisplayTag Library Framework

Tags: java, struts2

I want to apply pagination for some class of my application, in which i am using spring, struts2 & hibernate. Here i am calling action class from welcome.jsp file. It has following code :

```
<s:form action="marketing/allCountry.action">  
         <s:submit value="Click"></s:submit>  
         </s:form>
```

Now my `allCountry.action` class of java has following code :

```
public String executeAction() throws Exception {
        try {
            countryList = new ArrayList<Country>();
            countryList = this.countrySecurityProcessor.findByAll(0, null, null, null, null, false, false, null, null, null, null, 0);
            System.out.println("countryList = "+countryList);
            return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return ActionSupport.ERROR;
        }
}
```

It fetches the data properly, that i confirmed by printing countryList object. But now i am redirecting from `SUCCESS` to `country.jsp`. The code of `country.jsp` is :

```
<display:table list="countryList" requestURI="CountryAllAction" pagesize="3">
    <display:column property="id" title="ID" />
    <display:column property="name" />
</display:table>
```

Now at the time executing my application i am getting run time error like :

> javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   Exception: [.LookupUtil] Error looking up property "id" in object type
>   "java.lang.String". Cause: Unknown property 'id'

What is the solution to this type of error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a getter for your countryList in your action.

```
List<Country> countryList = new ArrayList<Country>();

public String executeAction() throws Exception {
  try {
     countryList = this.countrySecurityProcessor.findByAll(0, null, null, null, null, false, false, null, null, null, null, 0);
     System.out.println("countryList = "+countryList);
     return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;

  } catch (Exception ex) {
     return ActionSupport.ERROR;
  }

}

public List<Country> getCountryList() {
  return countryList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Struts2 but it seems that DisplayTag can't find your countryList in any scope.

I don't see you putting countryList in from or request. If I'm not right may be you need to specify form name like
`<display:table list="${yourStrutsFormName.countryList}" ...`

Answer (score 0):

You need make "countryList" available to DisplayTag, e.g. by doing something like:

```
   request.setAttribute("countryList", countryList);
```

in your action (unless there's a cleverer Struts2 way of doing this). I think you can get hold of the request in your action by making it implement [ServletRequestAware](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.6/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/ServletRequestAware.html)

You also need to make sure that your Country class has id and name properties.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code.Instead of list attribute use name attribute.

```
<display:table name="countryList" requestURI="CountryAllAction" pagesize="3">
 <display:column property="id" title="ID" />
 <display:column property="name" />
</display:table>
```

Answer (score 0):

u dont need to do any thing just use list variable in display tag name i.e

```
<display:table name="yourListnameinaction">

</display>
```