# Using a pagination with Struts 2 and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, struts2, pagination

I'm looking for ideas to implement a pagination with Struts2 and Hibernate. 
My table contains too many lines and it should be as I can see only 20 at a time, for example. With `PREVIOUS` and `NEXT` buttons.

Comment: ok i have found this http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/  what do you think ? knowing in my app i have fitch data in iterator

Comment: DisplayTag works. But it's over ten years old... I would stick with something new (see jQGrid or others).

Comment: Ok if you have already used please put an exemple as an answer

Comment: @stoner The example is below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pagination example is [here](http://prathap-puppala.blogspot.com/2011/06/struts-2-pagination-example.html). As I've already explained in my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14876945/573032) displaytag is a good library and was popular about decade, it's open source, so you could easily grab ideas from the sources, however you can use it as is, and it's not easy to modify it to suit your needs. That's why you are looking for ideas. Thanks the guy on the web who share the ideas that I agree with, you can find in his code example.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement pagination in struts2 and hibernate the best library I would suggest would be [Struts2Jquery Plugin](http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action)...

In the widgets menu.. see the GRID section. It implements pagination for you with more add-on facilities that you would like to have. And the best part.. you write least javascript for it.. Try it.. I am currently using it in my project!